# Term for strengthening the bond between an employee and his organisation

Tags: synonyms

**Edit: added one-sidedness of 'Employee retention' as an issue**

I'm looking for an alternative to 'Employee retention'. Intuitively, I interpret 'retention' as a defensive term, while I mean to emphasise (strengthening of) the bond between an employee and their company in a positive way.

Additionally, 'Employee retention' is a one-sided term, in that it is primarily applicable when considering the bond from company's perspective.

In Dutch, we have the (to me) more neutral term *medewerkersbinding*. In German, there's the equivalent term *Mitarbeiterbindung* ([Wikipedia, using Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMitarbeiterbindung)).

Does such a term exist in English?

Comment: The "bond" is often considered to be a function of "morale", and "morale-boosting" activities/programs are often implemented by companies to improve the "bond".

Comment: Mitarbeiterbindung and medewerkersbinding both translate to : *Contributors bond*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are looking for is [***employee engagement***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_engagement)?

It is sometimes defined as an employee's involvement with, commitment to, and satisfaction with work. It bridges job satisfaction and organizational commitment and is part of employee retention.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_engagement

Comment: That still seems one-sided, albeit from the employee's perspective this time (just now realizing that the one-sidedness of 'retention' is another part of my issue with it). Still, it's a well-defined term and far more positive than retention, so definitely the better option. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

> [Team building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_building) is a collective term for various types of activities used to enhance social relations and define roles within teams, often involving collaborative tasks. It is distinct from team training, which is designed to improve the efficiency, rather than interpersonal relations. –Wiki

Comment: Any reason why you use community wiki? I still don't get it.

Comment: @Rathony - This literally took me 30 seconds. This comment took more work then that answer. Really it's because I added absolutely nothing onto what Wiki said. It's CWed, not to make it more accessible to edits or w/e (by all means, do), but because I believe this level of effort deserves no points. It's a *comment of an answer*; just happens to be where it belongs ;)